# Why is $\{1, (x - a), (x - a)²,...,( x - a)^n\}$ a basis??

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't understand why $\{1, (x - a), (x - a)²,...,( x - a)^n\}$, $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is a basis of the vector space $R[x]≤n$.

Would really appreciate some tips.

Comment: You should look up the definition of a vector space and the basis of vector space. Also first try to solve $B_1=\{1,(x-a)\}$ and then try to use induction to prove the general result.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Because it is a system of generators by *Taylor's formula*  (which is an exact formula for polynomials).

Answer (score 1):

The map $f(x) \mapsto f(x-a)$ is an automorphism of that space.

Therefore, the image of the basis $\{1,x,x^2,\dots,x^n$} is also a basis.